# How do you determine the amount of mass for both a solid and diffuse object?

Tags: integration, density-function

Given the value $K$ multiplied by radius $r$, I can determine the amount of mass of the solid red sphere at the center of the image using the following: $K * r = mass$.

However, $K$ begins to diminish as $r$ increases past the radius of the solid sphere.

As such, how do I calculate the amount of mass between any two regions between $r1$ and $r2$? I assume it would be an integral with the following form $\int_{r1}^{r2} K(r) * r \,dr$, but I could be mistaken.

But more importantly, in a unified expression, how do I calculate the total amount of mass in both the solid red sphere plus the amount of mass in the diffused area up to some radius greater than the radius of the solid red sphere?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What are the units of $K$?  From your first equation it is $mass/distance$.  In that case, if $K(r)$ (which you call a constant but say it varies with $r$) has the same units your integral has units of mass*distance.  As you are asking it, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Normally $K$ would be a density, so for the inner part the mass would be $\frac 43\pi K r^3$ and the integral would be $\int K(r) 4 \pi r^2 \; dr$ but maybe your $K$ is different.  Please check and edit the post if necessary.

Comment: As strange as this sounds, $K$ is a set value within the solid sphere and only becomes a function of radius outside of the sphere. I know that density x volume gives you mass. But in this case, this isn't necessary. I only want to know, do I need two separate equations as they are to describe to overall system and if so how would you write that down on paper?

Comment: Your units are still different between the inner part and the outer part.  In the inner part it is mass/distance.  In the outer part it is mass/distance^2  I wouldn't use K for both of them-I would give a new symbol.  Other than that it is a fine way to write the mass interior to r2.  I would probably prefer to make the symbol you use be a density, so define $C=K/r^2$ inside and $K/r$ outside and use $C$ and $C(r)$

Comment: ok, I edited my question to make to easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined it, the mass interior to $r$ is $Kr$.  You are correct that if $K$ varies you need to integrate to get the mass in a spherical shell.  Presumably that integral starts from $r$, so the mass interior to $r2$ would be $$Kr+\int_r^{r2}K(r)r\;dr$$
There is nothing wrong with having the integral if the radius is greater than $r$ and not if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't the integral range from an infinitesimal value greater the $r$ to $r2$, and not from $r$ to $r2$?

Comment: No, it should start at $r$.  There is no infinitesimal value greater than $r$.  Think of it in 1D.  You have a function that is $1$ on the range $0$ to $1$ and $\frac 1x$ for $x \gt 1$.  You would have the integral start at $1$.